# MySQL insert into with subquery Select

Tags: php, mysql, insert, subquery

Basically, I'd like to insert into table, getting values id from the same table,something like this

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO commande (idfichecmd,idproduit,idclt,qte,datecmd)
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)+1 ,'1' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$fb' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'2' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$g' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'3' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$pi' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'4' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$ft' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'5' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$sd' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'6' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$ad' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'7' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$vs' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'8' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$wi' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'9' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$equip' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'10' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$fo' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande),
(SELECT MAX(idfichecmd) ,'11' AS idproduit ,'$idC' AS idclt ,'$fh' AS qte,'$date' FROM commande)")or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Unable to add commande : ". mysql_error());   
mysql_close();
```

owever, this one does not work, anyone know why?

Comment: this is really not readable! format it better! Also what is the failure, provide more information!

Comment: post the value of $sql, that will help to answer this.

Comment: removed the Android tag ... and please, give us the returned error : what it is behind 'does not work' ?

Comment: Please, forma your SQL with http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html):

```sql
INSERT INTO commande (idfichecmd, idproduit, idclt, qte, datecmd)
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)+1,  1, '$idC', '$fb'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  2, '$idC', '$g'    , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  3, '$idC', '$pi'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  4, '$idC', '$ft'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  5, '$idC', '$sd'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  6, '$idC', '$ad'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  7, '$idC', '$vs'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  8, '$idC', '$wi'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  ,  9, '$idC', '$equip', '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  , 10, '$idC', '$fo'   , '$date' FROM commande
UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(idfichecmd)  , 11, '$idC', '$fh'   , '$date' FROM commande
```

But it might be easier to first obtain the `MAX(idfichecmd)` in PHP, then  use `INSERT ... VALUES` (remembering to perform the operation in a transaction in order to preserve atomicity):

```sql
INSERT INTO commande (idfichecmd, idproduit, idclut, qte, datecmd) VALUES
  ($id+1, 1, '$idC', '$fb', '$date'),
  ($id  , 2, '$idC', '$g' , '$date'),
  -- etc.
```

Or, if you are merely looking to give each new record an incremented `idfichecmd`, consider making the column [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) (whereby MySQL will do all of this for you automatically):

```sql
ALTER TABLE commande MODIFY idfichecmd INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO commande (idproduit, idclut, qte, datecmd) VALUES
  (1, '$idC', '$fb', '$date'),
  (2, '$idC', '$g' , '$date'),
  -- etc.
```